# Php uploading a file & creating a directory

Tags: php, html, apache, directory, shared-hosting

English is not my first/second language and i have no idea how to word this out but ill try explain on what im trying to do.
I'm not asking for someone to straight up do this for me but guide me through on where to start, as of right now i have no idea what to even search on google.
Basically i have a domain which is on a shared host. Mostly for testing purposes so i dont really care about security or any of that sort since nothing important/sensitive is being uploaded on my domain.

So basically often i have to login through FTP and create a new folder & add a simple premade index.html file which gets tiring when i have to do the same task 10+ times a day.
So i was thinking, what if i create a simple UI which i can simply put in the directory name & attach the .html file so it can be done just like that. Without having to login through FTP.

Is it something easy? I was just thinking of just going on domain.com/create and having a simple UI where you just attach the .html file and the dir's name and just click "Submit".

I genuinely hope what i wrote makes any sort of sense because i have no idea where to start.
If you read this til the end seriously, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is fairly easy as long as you don't care about security ;)

You want to look at [`mkdir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) and [`move_uploaded_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file). Collect the directory name and the file in a form, create the directory, and move the uploaded file there. The example code in the documentation I linked to should be enough to make it work.

[Edit] Here is an example of how to do this in a somewhat safe way. This is as bare-bones as it gets. Disclaimer - allowing file uploads into your web root is dangerous. I am not responsible is someone owns your server!

```
<?php
//Set up variables we will need later
$directoryName = '';
$status        = 'init';
$errorMessage  = '';

//A super secret password that is required in order to do the dangerous things
$password = 'secret!';

//If submit is in the post (result of the submit button being pressed)
if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))
{
    try
    {
        //Get the directory name input first so we can set it back in the field if the login fails
        $directoryName = $_POST['directory_name'];

        //First verify the password
        $passwordEntry = $_POST['password'];
        if ($passwordEntry != $password)
        {
            throw new Exception('Authentication error');
        }

        //If the directory name is blank, bail out
        if (empty($directoryName))
        {
            throw new Exception('Directory name is required');
        }

        //Make sure nobody can traverse from the root of the filesystem
        if (substr($directoryName, 0, 1) == '/')
        {
            $directoryName = substr($directoryName, 1);
        }

        /*
         * Get rid of slashes and anything after them. After this, if someone entered
         * "/etc/passwd", we would have "etc"
         */
        $directoryName = preg_replace('/\/(.*)?/', '', $directoryName);

        //If the directory already exists, bail out
        if (file_exists($directoryName))
        {
            throw new Exception('Directory already exists');
        }

        //Make sure we have a file in the request. If not, bail out.
        if (empty($_FILES["index_file"]["tmp_name"]))
        {
            throw new Exception('Please upload a file');
        }

        //Create our directory
        mkdir($directoryName);

        //Get the temporary path to the file - this is where the server stashed it
        $tmpName = $_FILES["index_file"]["tmp_name"];

        //Create a path to where we want the file
        $destinationPath = $directoryName . '/index.html';

        //Attempt to move the file, this return true on success, false on failure
        $fileMoveStatus = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $destinationPath);

        //If the file could not be moved, remove the directory we created an bail out
        if ($fileMoveStatus === false)
        {
            rmdir($directoryName);
            throw new Exception('Unable to move file to destination');
        }

        //Change the permissions on the HTML file so nobody can monkey with it
        chmod($directoryName . '/index.html', 0644);

        /*
         * Reset the directory name - we put this variable in the field so the user
         * won't have to re-type it if an error occurs. We want it to be empty now
         * that the process was successful
         */
        $directoryName = '';

        // Set the status to success so we display the success alert to the user
        $status = 'success';
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        // Set the status to error so we display the error alert to the user
        $status = 'error';

        // Set the error message to the message from the exception
        $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Directory Manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Directory Manager</h1>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php
        if ($status == 'error')
        {
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <?php echo $errorMessage; ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        elseif ($status == 'success')
        {
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                File uploaded successfully<br>
                <a href="<?php echo $destinationPath; ?>">Go to file</a>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="directory_name">Directory Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="directory_name" id="directory_name" aria-describedby="directory_name_help" value="<?php echo $directoryName ?>">
                    <small id="directory_name_help" class="form-text text-muted">Name of directory to be
                        created.</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="directory_name">HTML File</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="index_file" id="index_file" aria-describedby="file_help">
                    <small id="file_help" class="form-text text-muted">index.html file</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Edit 2] A version that copies a template file rather than uploading.

```
<?php
//Set up variables we will need later
$directoryName = '';
$status        = 'init';
$errorMessage  = '';

//A super secret password that is required in order to do the dangerous things
$password = 'secret!';

// Path to the template file that will be copied into created directories
$sourcePath = 'template.html';

//If submit is in the post (result of the submit button being pressed)
if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))
{
    try
    {
        //Get the directory name input first so we can set it back in the field if the login fails
        $directoryName = $_POST['directory_name'];

        //First verify the password
        $passwordEntry = $_POST['password'];
        if ($passwordEntry != $password)
        {
            throw new Exception('Authentication error');
        }

        //If the directory name is blank, bail out
        if (empty($directoryName))
        {
            throw new Exception('Directory name is required');
        }

        //Make sure nobody can traverse from the root of the filesystem
        if (substr($directoryName, 0, 1) == '/')
        {
            $directoryName = substr($directoryName, 1);
        }

        /*
         * Get rid of slashes and anything after them. After this, if someone entered
         * "/etc/passwd", we would have "etc"
         */
        $directoryName = preg_replace('/\/(.*)?/', '', $directoryName);

        //If the directory already exists, bail out
        if (file_exists($directoryName))
        {
            throw new Exception('Directory already exists');
        }

        //Create our directory
        mkdir($directoryName);

        //Create a path to where we want the file
        $destinationPath = $directoryName . '/index.html';

        //Attempt to copy the file, this return true on success, false on failure
        $fileCopyStatus = copy($sourcePath, $destinationPath);

        //If the file could not be copied, remove the directory we created an bail out
        if ($fileCopyStatus === false)
        {
            rmdir($directoryName);
            throw new Exception('Unable to copy template file to destination');
        }

        //Change the permissions on the HTML file so nobody can monkey with it
        chmod($directoryName . '/index.html', 0644);

        /*
         * Reset the directory name - we put this variable in the field so the user
         * won't have to re-type it if an error occurs. We want it to be empty now
         * that the process was successful
         */
        $directoryName = '';

        // Set the status to success so we display the success alert to the user
        $status = 'success';
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        // Set the status to error so we display the error alert to the user
        $status = 'error';

        // Set the error message to the message from the exception
        $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Directory Manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Directory Manager</h1>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php
        if ($status == 'error')
        {
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <?php echo $errorMessage; ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        elseif ($status == 'success')
        {
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                File uploaded successfully<br>
                <a href="<?php echo $destinationPath; ?>">Go to file</a>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="directory_name">Directory Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="directory_name" id="directory_name" aria-describedby="directory_name_help" value="<?php echo $directoryName ?>">
                    <small id="directory_name_help" class="form-text text-muted">Name of directory to be
                        created.</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i can't quite well understand the example on how to collect the dir name or make it work as of right now, but atleast i have an idea on what i have to do. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome - I've added a working example that includes some basic safety precautions.

Comment: Quick question, is there a way to transfer the index.html file thats already in my webserver and skipping the upload part altogether? The file thats being uploaded is always the same. Once again thank you so so much. This looks better than anything i could ever make.

Comment: Sure, I added a version that does that. Just change the $sourcePath variable to point to the file you want to copy into the new directory. You can do this! Just take some time to figure out what all the pieces are doing.